# load page inside page with iframe

Tags: jquery, html, django, iframe

I am working on a django project (but I think it is nothing to do with django).

On one of my web page, I want to load another page into an ifame element. So basically, it is 'page inside a page'.

I made it and it works, somehow.

The way I do it is:

```
$('#sub_web_page').attr('src', URL);
```

where $('#sub_web_page') is a ifame element and 'URL' is a url that point to the page I want to load.

This approach just works fine except two cases.

First one, if I want to load URL like 'http://www.yahoo.com', it won't show up (even I wait extremely long time). I think the reason is that 'yahoo' page is large to load. The same problem happened with some another pages.
Is there a way to solve it?

Second one is more fatal and weird. When I try to load 'http://www.msn.com', instead of loading page into iframe, my whole page was redirected to MSN. I haven't find another URL which may cause the same problem, but it is already weird enough.

Does anyone know the solution for any of problem above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites don't allow to be embedded in a iframe. With various detection algorithms, they detect that they are in iframe and thus take action like getting blank or loading on top of parent.

Going against this can lead to very complex javascript. Read this :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html